# How to export faces from mesh as another mesh?

Tags: modeling, mesh

Perhaps I am missing something pretty obvious and simple, but can't find the way to get copy of some faces of existing mesh as new mesh.

Say, I have some comlicated mesh, and I want to get some part of it but as new mesh. Mesh is too complicated to use boolean to "cut" the part that I do not need, for example.

Comment: What do you mean by "Mesh is too complicated to use boolean to "cut" the part that I do not need", could you please show a screenshot?

Comment: @moonboots Currently I have just jsut some cubes combined by boolean in one mesh, but You can consider probably any high-poly model as "complicated mesh"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you select several faces, you can press <kbd>P</kbd> to separate them from the rest of the mesh, or you can separate by material, or by loose parts. The result will be two or more mesh objects where there was one.

Comment: Literally what do I need, except I do not need faces to be removed from original mesh, just be dublicated instead as new mesh. But it is good answer, anyway

Comment: Select the faces.  Duplicate them.  Then press P to separate the duplicates.

Answer (score 4):

You can

- Select the object containing the mesh;
- Enter edit mode;
- Select the faces you want to copy;
- Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>–<kbd>D</kbd> to duplicate the faces;
- Press right mouse button to exit move mode; and
- Press <kbd>P</kbd> and select *Selection* from the *Separate* popup menu:

[image: Separate menu]

This leaves the original faces intact in the original mesh and creates a new object containing copies of the selected faces

Comment: Thanks for feedback, @TheLabCat was first though

Comment: @Stdugnd4ikbd true, and I don't grudge them the points, so don't change the accept on my account, but they didn't solve your problem, leaving out the bit about duplicating.

Comment: I think the best decision is to upvote Your answer, because it is indeed better, but to keep first answer as accepted, because it is correct, and it was first.

Comment: @Stdugnd4ikbd I think that's a fine decision.